# Android listview row changing values

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a ListView that contains 3 types of elements. Rows and QueueRows that are a bit complicated sets of subcontrols, and HeaderRow containing only textView.
What I do is adding HeaderRow, few QueueRows, headerRow and few Rows.
QueueRow needs to be updated every second. That is why I wrote a code that calls notifyDataSetChanged on adapter. It updates queuerow every second, but there is also a problem - My two headers switch places for half a second.
After every 0,5s they swap. Do you have any ideas how to prevent them?

That is my code:

```
class BuildingsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BaseRow> {

private static Bitmap SOURCE_BITMAP;

private MainActivity mainActivity_;

private Handler handler_;
private Runnable runnable_;

public BuildingsAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity) {

    super(mainActivity, R.layout.row);
    this.mainActivity_ = mainActivity;
    SOURCE_BITMAP = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            mainActivity_.getResources(), R.drawable.images);
    handler_ = new Handler();
    runnable_ = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (hasQueueItems())
                handler_.postDelayed(runnable_, 1000);
        }
    };
}

@Override
public void add(BaseRow object) {

    if (!hasQueueItems() && object.getClass().equals(QueueRow.class))
        handler_.postDelayed(runnable_, 1000);
    super.add(object);
}

private boolean hasQueueItems() {

    for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); ++i) {
        if (getItem(i).getClass().equals(QueueRow.class))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    return getItem(position).getType();
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {

    return 3;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    int type = getItemViewType(position);

    View row = convertView;

    switch (type) {
    case BaseRow.QUEUE_ROW: {
        QueueRowViewHolder holder = new QueueRowViewHolder();
        //whatever
                    return convertView;
    }
    case BaseRow.ROW: {
        RowViewHolder holder = new RowViewHolder();
        //whatever
                    return convertView;
    }
    case BaseRow.HEADER_ROW: {
        HeaderViewHolder holder = new HeaderViewHolder();
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_row, parent, false);

            HeaderRow headerRow = (HeaderRow) getItem(position);

            holder.nameTextView_ = (TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.categoryNameTextView);
            holder.nameTextView_.setText(headerRow.getName());

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (HeaderViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        return row;
    }
    }
    return null;
}

static class QueueRowViewHolder {

    ImageView qItemImageView_;
    TextView qItemNameTextView_;
    ProgressBar qProgressBar_;
    TextView qLevelTextView_;
    TextView qTimeTextView_;
    int position_;
}

static class RowViewHolder {

    ImageView itemImageView_;
    TextView nameTextView_;
    TextView levelTextView_;
    TextView woodTextView_;
    TextView ironTextView_;
    TextView stoneTextView_;
    TextView goldTextView_;
    Button actionButton_;
    TextView timeTextView_;
}

static class HeaderViewHolder {

    TextView nameTextView_;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem but you should have `break` statements in your `switch/case`

Comment: Maybe there is a better way to update just QueueRows?

Comment: Maybe but if you put in a `break` statement then the other code in the `switch` is sure not to run. Is there a reason you don't have it in there?

Comment: Yes - there are returns ;) I cut them off, but they are there. I've updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok! I've found it out - I didn't set the values of HeaderRow ;)